# Switch caseProblem PHP - do something if last case is displayed

Tags: php, switch-statement, case

I came across huge problem with SWITCH CASE statement in PHP, I have dynamic switch, case construction, which I displaying below in static way as example. Each case got form and 1 input field, once submitted we are moving to other case, and that till all them are submitted. Problem is I would like to add extra input filed  if last form from last case is submitted? How can I do it? Please ask if I am not clear.

```
<?php
while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($check_number)) { 

$i = $row['i'];


switch($step);

case $i:

?>
<form>

// add extra input field if last case

</form>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Your question is extremely difficult to understand and will likely get closed but if had to take a guess then I think you want: `case "green": $_POST['extraInputField'] = 1; break;`

Comment: edited question now it should be really clear

Comment: One issue is your `switch()` should be outside your `while` loop. Also you shouldn't be using `mysql_` functions.

Comment: To add a field on last one you would need to check to see how many results you have then do a counter as you go through the results to see if you are on the last result.